# Combine two arrays together

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array
(
    [name] => name
    [description] => description here
    [first] => Array
        (
            [0] => weight
            [1] => height
        )
    [second] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 kg
            [1] => 50 cm
        )
    [company_id] => 1
    [category_id] => 7
)
```

what function will allow me to combine these into something that looks like the following?

```
array
(
    [together]
        (
            [0] => weight 20kg
            [1] => height 50cm 
        )
)
```

Comment: Is it always just going to be two indices? Or are there *n* indices and you want to combine `first[n]` with `second[n]` (BTW, that's pretty close to the actual syntax you need...).

Comment: it will always come out as [first] and [second]  and i will need to combine [first][0] with [second][0] and so on.  I know how to do this with loops etc... but i wanted to see if there was a function made for this that i could use

Comment: Why not simply concatenate them when you it is always be the same?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

For that current array you need to use the loop.

```
$first = $second = array();
foreach($yourArray as $key => $array) {
    if(in_array($key, array('first', 'second')) {
        $first[] = $array[0];
        $second[] = $array[1];
    }
}
$final['together'] = array($first, $second);
```

**According to the first array**

You can try this -

```
$new = array(
    'together' => array(
       implode(' ', array_column($yourArray, 0)), // This would take out all the values in the sub arrays with index 0 and implode them with a blank space
       implode(' ', array_column($yourArray, 1)), // Same as above with index 1
    )
);
```

`array_column` is supported **PHP >= 5.5**

Or you can try -

```
$first = $second = array();
foreach($yourArray as $array) {
    $first[] = $array[0];
    $second[] = $array[1];
}
$final['together'] = array($first, $second);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, however do you mind explaining the first answer?

my array above which shows [first] and [second]  actually has more like [name] and [description].

So how does this know what which ones i wanted to combine?

Comment: should i be using your updated post instead of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

you also can try `array_map` as below

```js
function merge($first,$second)
{
 return $first ." ".$second; 
}
$combine = array_map('merge', $yourArray[0],$yourArray[1]);
```